# Random bytes generation in c++11

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, random, function-parameter

I've written a funtion to prouduce random bytes in a `uint8_t` type array, unless I seed this with a `random_device` object it works fine but when I seed there are some compiler errors.

code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <stdint>

void generateInitVector(uint8_t IV_buff[16])
{
    using bytes_randomizer = std::independent_bits_engine<std::default_random_engine, CHAR_BIT, uint8_t>;
    std::random_device rd;
    bytes_randomizer bytes(rd);

    std::generate(std::begin(IV_buff), std::end(IV_buff), std::ref(bytes));
}
```

compiler errors:

```
1. error: no matching function for call to 'begin(uint8_t*&)'|

2. error: request for member 'begin' in '__cont', which is of non-class type 'unsigned char*'|

3. error: request for member 'begin' in '__cont', which is of non-class type 'unsigned char* const'|

4. error: no matching function for call to 'end(uint8_t*&)'|

5. error: request for member 'begin' in '__cont', which is of non-class type 'unsigned char*'|

6. error: request for member 'end' in '__cont', which is of non-class type 'unsigned char* const'|

7. error: 'class std::random_device' has no member named 'generate'|
```

There's catch that if I define a `uint8_t` type array within th function

```
uint8_t data[16];
std::generate(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::ref(bytes));  //and pass this array in `generate()`.
```

then only error 7 remains.  Any solutions to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: Use `std::array`.

Comment: @SombreroChicken can you please elaborate.

Comment: @UnholySheep can you demonstrate how can I implement the solution to which you redirected me.

Comment: You cannot use `uint8_t` here anyway. Only `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` or their unsigned counterparts, depending on the situations, are allowed as template parameters in `<random>`. Even `int64_t` and the like are potentially UB, although that is a purely theoretical concern.

Comment: @Nilesh, UnholySheep posted a rod, not a fish. What you are trying to do is incorrect, because passing array makes it decay to a bare pointer. You would have to pass size as another argument (and it still won't allow you to use iterators on it). `std::array` or `std::vector` is better solution here, as it won't decay and is generally better than C arrays.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  `std::array` doesn't gain the OP anything.  They just need to pass the array by reference.

Comment: `std::generate(IV_buff, IV_buff + 16, ...)`

Comment: can you please suggest anything on error 7 also

Comment: None of the constructors of `std::independent_bits_engine<std::default_random_engine, ...>` take `std::random_device` as a parameter. There's a templated constructor taking a `SeedSequence`, but `std::random_device` does not satisfy the requirements of `SeedSequence` (in particular, it doesn't have a method named `generate`, hence the last error). It's not clear to me what you were trying to do there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that even though your function looks like

```
void generateInitVector(uint8_t IV_buff[16])
```

What it really is, thanks to the array decaying into a pointer is

```
void generateInitVector(uint8_t * IV_buff)
```

So, because you have a pointer, you cannot use `std::begin` and `std::end`.  What you need to do is pass the array by reference to keep it an array.  That looks like

```
void generateInitVector(uint8_t (&IV_buff)[16])
```

and now you can use `std::begin` and `std::end` and you maintain the size information of the array.  You can even make it generic for the size using a template like

```
template<std::size_t N>
void generateInitVector(uint8_t (&IV_buff)[N])
{
    using bytes_randomizer = std::independent_bits_engine<std::default_random_engine, CHAR_BIT, uint8_t>;
    std::random_device rd;
    bytes_randomizer bytes(rd);

    std::generate(std::begin(IV_buff), std::end(IV_buff), std::ref(bytes));
}
```

You also have an issue with

```
bytes_randomizer bytes(rd);
```

`std::independent_bits_engine` expects a PRNG of the type of the first template parameter.  You used `std::default_random_engine` which is not the same as `std::random_device`.  You will need to change one of them to match the other in order for it to compile. For example:

```
template<std::size_t N>
void generateInitVector(uint8_t (&IV_buff)[N])
{
    using bytes_randomizer = std::independent_bits_engine<std::default_random_engine, CHAR_BIT, uint8_t>;
    std::default_random_engine rd;
    bytes_randomizer bytes(rd);

    std::generate(std::begin(IV_buff), std::end(IV_buff), std::ref(bytes));
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t data[16];
    generateInitVector(data);
}
```

[Compiles just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2843cb1fe750f5c3)